# Which file explorer has Mercurial support?

Tags: nautilus, filemanager, mercurial

I know Nautilus has support for Mercurial, but I'm not seeing the icon overlays even after installing tortoisehg-nautilus on Ubuntu 14.04.

I'm interested in knowing which Linux file explorers (both GUI and terminal curses) have support for Mercurial?

That is, if I look at the files and directories in the file explorer, I should be able to quickly see which of them are not in the repository, which are modified and which are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

[Kate](http://kate-editor.org/) editor has a plugin that supports mercurial git and subversion. I did not try it personally with mercurial but I guess it should work if they say it supports it.

You can search your self for more editors, here is a [list with some text editors](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux%20text%20editors):